# Problems with Jetty websocket and HTML5

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, jetty

I created a simple chat server in Java with a Javascript client , but I'm having a problem receiving messages from JavaScript to Java.

When i use the Java client it is work fine, but when i use Javascript i have the problem.

My code:

Java

```
public class ChatRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);
        try {
            ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer
                    .configureContext(context);
            wscontainer.addEndpoint(ChatEndpoint.class);
        server.start();
        server.dump(System.err);
        server.join();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}

@ServerEndpoint(value="/events/")
public class ChatEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess) {
        System.out.println("Socket Connected: " + sess);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received TEXT message: " + message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onWebSocketClose(CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("Socket Closed: " + reason);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/events/"); 
ws.onopen = function() {  ws.send("Hello");  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can test your server using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. Simply put your global url and test.

Comment: Server get only connect log... and it request data URL:ws://localhost:8080/events/?encoding=text
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols